# Prove that $\frac 1 {x+y}+\frac 1 {y+z}+\frac 1 {z+x}\geq \frac 5 2$.

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inequality, substitution, symmetric-polynomials, uvw

> Given:
>
> 1. $x,y,z\geq0$
> 2. $xy+yz+zx=1$
>
> Prove that $\displaystyle \frac 1 {x+y}+\frac 1 {y+z}+\frac 1 {z+x}\geq \frac 5 2$.

I tried using Cauchy's inequality LHS $\geq\frac 9 {2a+2b+2c}$, but failed. Please give me some ideas. Thank you.

Comment: Did you try to use Lagrange multipliers ? Some context may be usefull

Comment: I haven't heard of Lagrange multipliers...

Comment: Did you try expanding, assuming, WLOG x<y<z and using rearrangement inequality? It should work.

Comment: I tried, but nothing happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assume $z$ is the smallest.
if we fix the sum $x+y$,

$\dfrac{1}{x+y} + \dfrac{1}{z+x}+\dfrac{1}{z+y} = \dfrac{1}{x+y} +\dfrac{x+y+2z}{1+z^2}$, take it as a function of $z$, you may see, it is increasing.[you may differentiate it or just plugin $z=0$ and compare]

Thus $z=0$, it will be smallest.

The rest is easy.

---

Update:

After we get $z=0$, the restriction on $x,y,z$ turns out to be $xy=1$, and the goal is to minimize

$\dfrac{1}{x+y}+x+y$

Since now $x=\dfrac{1}{y}$, thus

$\dfrac{1}{x+y} +x+y = \dfrac{1}{x+\dfrac{1}{x}}+x+\dfrac{1}{x}$. Take $t = x+\dfrac{1}{x}$, we know that $t\ge 2$. then the objective function is to minimize

$$t+\dfrac{1}{t}$$

for $t\ge 2$.

You can take a derivative to see that $t+1/t$ is increasing when $t\ge 1$. So minimum will be obtained at $t = 2$. which is $x=y=1$.

Comment: When you fix the sum $x+y$, $z$ can only take one value based on the restriction $xy+yz+zx$=1; is it meaningful to take the expression as a function of $z$?

Comment: when I fix $x+y$, $z$ still can change. I only fix the sum, the product can change.

Comment: @VincentTjeng even you don't fix the sum, you can also see when $z=0$,by taking partial derivative w.r.t $z$, the function will obtain the minimum.

Comment: @Yimin: What are the rest? Minimum of $x+y+1/(x+y)$ is 2, not 5/2 ...

Comment: @jasoncube, you have $z=0$, then there is a restriction on $xy=1$.

Comment: @Yimin I really can't figure out the next step.

Comment: @jasoncube I added some notes on it.

Comment: I get it. One more question, why should we assume $z$ to be the smallest?

Comment: @jasoncube just for convenience, you may assume any of them as the smallest, but you know, only the smallest can be $0$.

Comment: Thanks for you help. I understand it completely now.

Comment: I don't think the solution of Yimin is true,please check it again.

Comment: @pxchg1200 well, did I miss anything?

Comment: @Yimin, I think if we take as a function of z,then it's not a increase function as you said.

Comment: @pxchg1200 $\dfrac{x+y+2z}{1+z^2} - \dfrac{x+y}{1} = \dfrac{x+y+2z-(x+y)(1+z^2)}{1+z^2} = \dfrac{z(2-zx-zy)}{1+z^2}\ge 0$, this is what I want.

Comment: differentiate it $(\dfrac{x+y+2z}{1+z^2})_z = \dfrac{2(1+z^2) - 2z(x+y+2z)}{(1+z^2)^2} = \dfrac{(2-2zy-2zx)-2z^2}{(1+z^2)^2} = \dfrac{2xy-2z^2}{(1+z^2)^2}\ge 0$, since $z$ is the smallest.@pxchg1200

Answer (score 6):

Well,I think you can use the famouse Iran 96 inequality as a result to solve this problem.
the Iran 96 inequality

Let $x,y,z\geq 0$ we have

$$ \frac{1}{(x+y)^{2}}+\frac{1}{(y+z)^{2}}+\frac{1}{(x+z)^{2}}\geq \frac{9}{4(xy+yz+zx)} $$
square both side,we can rewrite the inequality into
$$ \sum_{cyc}{\frac{1}{(x+y)^{2}}}+2\sum_{cyc}{\frac{1}{(x+y)(x+z)}}\geq \frac{25}{4}$$
Now,Using this inequality as a known result,it's suffice to prove
$$ \sum_{cyc}{\frac{1}{(x+y)(x+z)}}\geq 2 $$
after simple homogenous,it's
$$ (xy+yz+xz)(x+y+z)\geq (x+y)(y+z)(z+x) $$
Or
$$ xyz\geq 0 $$
Which is obviously true,Equality occurs if and only if $x=y=1, z=0 $ or it's permutation.
The proof is complete

Answer (score 2):

Let $x+y+z=3u$, $xy+xz+yz=3v^2$ and $xyz=w^3$.
Hence, the condition does not depend on $w^3$ and we need to prove that
$$\frac{\sum\limits_{cyc}(x^2+3xy)}{\prod\limits_{cyc}(x+y)}\geq\frac{5}{2}$$ or
$$\frac{9u^2+3v^2}{9uv^2-w^3}\geq\frac{5}{2}$$ or
$f(w^3)\geq0$, where $f$ is an increasing function.

Thus, it's enough to prove our inequality for a minimal value of $w^3$,
which happens in the following cases.

1. $y=x$, $z=\frac{1-x^2}{2x}$, where $0<x\leq1$ and we get something obvious;
2. $w^3=0$.

Let $z=0$. Hence, we need to prove that
$$\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{x+y}\geq\frac{5}{2}$$ or
$$x+y+\frac{1}{x+y}\geq\frac{5}{2}$$ or
$$(x+y-2)(2(x+y)-1)\geq0,$$
which is true because $x+y\geq2\sqrt{xy}=2$ and we are done!

Answer (score 2):

**Proof.**

By using AM-GM $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{a+b+c}{a+b}=\sum_{cyc}\left(ab+c(a+b)+\frac{c}{a+b}\right)\ge \sum_{cyc}(2c+ab)=2(a+b+c)+1 .$$
Thus,$$\frac{1}{a+b}+\frac{1}{b+c}+\frac{1}{c+a}\ge 2+ \frac{1}{a+b+c}\ge \frac{5}{2},$$which is true for $\sqrt{3}\le a+b+c\le 2.$

Now, it's enough to prove the OP in case  $p=a+b+c>2$.

Indeed, by using Cauchy- Schwarz $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+b}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{(c+1)^2}{(a+b)(c+1)^2}\ge \frac{(a+b+c+3)^2}{\sum_{cyc}(a+b)(c+1)^2}.$$It's equivalent to $$2(p+3)^2\ge 5\left(3p-3r+4\right), $$since $r\ge 0,$ we will prove $$2p^2-3p-2\ge 0 \iff (2p+1)(p-2)\ge 0,$$which is obvious by $p\ge 2.$

Hence, the proof is done. Equality holds at $a=b=1;c=0$ and cyclic permutations.