# How can they know what type of inequality to use?

Tags: inequality

Let: $x,y,z \ge 0$ and $xy+yz+zx=1$. Prove that: $$\frac{1}{x+y}+\frac{1}{y+z}+\frac{1}{z+x} \ge \frac{5}{2}$$

Here is the solution:

Square both sides and add $(xy+yz+zx)$ in LHS, we have:
$$(xy+yz+zx)(\frac{1}{x+y}+\frac{1}{y+z}+\frac{1}{z+x})^2 \ge \frac{25}{4}$$

which can be rewritten as:$$(\sum_{sym}^{}x^5y-\sum_{sym}^{}x^4y^2)+3(\sum_{sym}^{}x^5y-\sum_{sym}^{}x^3y^3)+(\sum_{sym}^{}x^4yz+14\sum_{sym}^{}x^3y^2z+38x^2y^2z^2)\ge 0$$ which is true by Murihead!

My questions are how can they knew how to square both sides and add $(xy+yz+zx)$ to $LHS$, and in the last line of solution, how can they knew when to use Murihead. I'm so confuse when to use Murihead, when to use Weighted AM-GM or Rearrangement inequality. Thank you for all your helps!

Comment: There is a proof which just use Cauchy-Schwarz

Comment: See also here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319432/prove-that-frac-1-xy-frac-1-yz-frac-1-zx-geq-frac-5-2.

Comment: I feel like the actual answer to your question is "practice and experience".

Comment: :))I don't think so, because when I was in low level class, my teacher always said that but when go higher I know there will be some reasons why they did that

Comment: You should use Muirhead if it appeared in the lectures in the week before the homework was given. Same applies to most other theorems, and it also applies to exercises following sections in books.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's just homogenization!

Muirhead works with homogeneous symmetric polynomials and homogenization helps to see a possibility to use Muirhead.

It's not always helps.

Another way.

Let $x+y+z\geq2.$

Thus, $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{x+y}=\sum_{cyc}\frac{xy+xz+yz}{x+y}=x+y+z+\sum_{cyc}\frac{xy}{x+y}\geq$$
$$\geq x+y+z+\sum_{cyc}\frac{xy}{x+y+z}=x+y+z+\frac{1}{x+y+z}\geq\frac{5}{2}.$$

Let $x+y+z\leq2$.

Thus, by C-S $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{x+y}=\frac{1}{x+y+z}\sum_{cyc}\frac{x+y+z}{x+y}=$$
$$=\frac{3}{x+y+z}+\frac{1}{x+y+z}\sum_{cyc}\frac{z}{x+y}\geq$$
$$\geq\frac{3}{x+y+z}+\frac{1}{x+y+z}\cdot\frac{(x+y+z)^2}{\sum\limits_{cyc}(xz+yz)}=$$
$$=\frac{3}{x+y+z}+\frac{x+y+z}{2}\geq\frac{5}{2}.$$

Comment: Nice proof! I also gave AM-GM and Cauchy-Schwarz proof which split into 2 cases: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/319432/prove-that-frac-1-xy-frac-1-yz-frac-1-zx-geq-frac-5-2

Answer (score 5):

*Alternative proof.*

By squaring both side of the OP, we'll prove that$$(ab+bc+ca)\left(\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{(b+c)^2}+2\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{(b+a)(c+a)}\right)\ge \frac{25}{4}.\tag{*}$$
Notice that $$2(ab+bc+ca)\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{(b+a)(c+a)}=4+\frac{4abc}{(a+b)(b+c)(c+a)}\ge 4. \tag{1}$$
WLOG, assuming that $c=\min\{a,b,c\}.$
We have $2(a+b)>(a+c)(b+c),$ thus
\begin{align*}
\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{(b+c)^2}&=\frac{1}{(b+a)^2}+\frac{2}{(b+c)(a+c)}+\frac{(a-b)^2}{(b+c)^2(a+c)^2}
\\&\ge \frac{1}{(b+a)^2}+\frac{2}{(b+c)(a+c)}+\frac{(a-b)^2}{4(a+b)^2}.
\end{align*}

> Proof for $2(a+b)>(a+c)(b+c).$ Since $c=\min\{a,b,c\},$ thus $1=ab+bc+ca\ge 3c^2$ and by AM-GM $$2(a+b)\ge a+c+b+c\ge 2\sqrt{(a+c)(b+c)}>(a+c)(b+c) \iff 4\ge (a+c)(b+c) \iff c^2<3.$$

Also,\begin{align*}
\frac{1}{(b+a)^2}&=\frac{ab+bc+ca}{(b+a)^2}\\&=\frac{ab}{(b+a)^2}+\frac{c}{a+b}\\&=\frac{ab}{(b+a)^2}+\frac{2c^2}{(a+c)(b+c)}+\frac{c(c-a)(c-b)}{(a+b)(a+c)(b+c)}\\&\ge \frac{ab}{(b+a)^2}+\frac{2c^2}{(a+c)(b+c)}.
\end{align*}
Hence
\begin{align*}
(ab+bc+ca)\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{(b+c)^2}&\ge \frac{ab}{(b+a)^2}+\frac{2c^2}{(a+c)(b+c)}+\frac{2(ab+bc+ca)}{(a+c)(b+c)}+\frac{(a-b)^2}{4(a+b)^2}\\&=\frac{9}{4}. \tag{2}
\end{align*}
From $(1)$ and $(2)$ we proved $(*).$

Hence, the proof is done. Equality holds at $a=b=1;c=0$ and its permutations.

Comment: Nice! Really in your proof you used the Ji Chen's inequality.

Comment: What is Jichen's inequality @MichaelRozenberg ?

Comment: $(xy+xz+yz)\sum\limits_{cyc}\frac{1}{(x+y)^2}\geq\frac{9}{4}.$

Comment: Oh, it is famous inequality. After solving the problem, I've felt it is quite similar.

Comment: Could you please tell me why $2(a+b)>(a+b)(a+c)$ ?

Answer (score 1):

Hint.

Calling $f(x,y) = \frac{1}{x+y}$ we have

$$
F(x,y,z) = f(x,y)+f(y,z)+f(z,x)
$$

and also

$$
\cases{
f(x,y) \le F(x,y,z)\\
f(y,z) \le F(x,y,z)\\
f(z,x) \le F(x,y,z)\\
}
$$

so the solution is reduced to determine the minimum of the problems

$$
\cases{
\min_{x,y}f(x,y), \ \ \text{s.t.}\ \ \ x y =1, x\ge 0, y\ge 0\\
\min_{y,z}f(y,z), \ \ \text{s.t.}\ \ \ y z =1, y\ge 0, z\ge 0\\
\min_{z,x}f(z,x), \ \ \text{s.t.}\ \ \ z x =1, z\ge 0, x\ge 0\\
}
$$